# Flutter pop() issue

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I'm working on a FLutter application and found a strange issue.

I have got this widget:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var route = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.name;
    return IconButton(
      icon: const Icon(
        UniconsLine.previous,
        shadows: [
          BoxShadow(
            blurRadius: 15.0,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
          BoxShadow(
            blurRadius: 15.0,
            color: mainBgColor,
          )
        ],
        size: 40,
      ),
      onPressed: () {
        print(route);
        Navigator.pop(context);
      },
    );
  }
```

What I'm trying to do is pop the content and go back to the previous page. Somehow, all I got is a blank page. The route is "/" here. On the other pages, the route is just null. When I'm using the Android navigation button it routes to the previous page.

What is the solution for this?

Comment: how  do you navigate to this widget?
do you `pushNamedAndRemoveUntil` ? maybe that caused the route to be null. because it will remove all the previous routes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
 Navigator.of(context).maybePop();
```

or

```
Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop(context);
```

If both not works try this

```
SystemNavigator.pop();
```